# circular jar reference - can it compile?

Tags: java, jar, compilation, circular-reference

I saw some questions about "circular jar references" in Java, and I'm not seeing something.

My question is: how is it possible to build two jars where each jar has method calls to classes in the other jar?  It seems that certain classes in each jar project would need to import classes from the other jar, and thus need to reference the the other jar in the class path for the build -- but the other jar can't be compiled due to the same need.

I could understand compiling all the classes as one big project and then packaging classes into separate jars with interdependencies, but it seems impossible to compile each jar's classes separately due to the need to include the other jar in the classpath.

The relevance to me is that I develop code into a jar for consumption by another project.  However, now I need to consume a few api calls from the other project.  The only way I see to do this would be to separate out some commonly consumed and independent api classes into a third project/jar that both the original two projects could include in their classpaths.

Is there another perspective on this?

Comment: You need some architect... ;-) Circular references must be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

They don't need to reference one another necessarily as jars at the compile time.  They can be two separate projects that reference one another as long as the classpath is configured at the time of the development to reflect that.

So you can have a use case scenario whereby:

```
Api1.Class11 references (or imports) Api2.Class21
```

and

```
Api2.Class22 references Api1.Class12
```

which is legal because, while a circular reference at the project level, it is not so at the class level (imagine if the two projects were consolidated into one and you had this scenario).

Once bundled into jars, it is the responsibility of a client application that uses them to include both in the classpath so that they can see each other that way at runtime.

Personally, I think this practice is confusing but it is possible to do.  I wouldn't use circular references myself for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like a chicken and egg situation to me -- the only way to get at least one jar built would be to compile all the classes in one project and then make the jar(s) as desired.  I agree I don't want to do this, which is why I'll propose we factor out a third jar if possible so all jars can be built independently when properly ordered.

Comment: if you liked the answer, consider upvoting and accepting as answer

Answer (score 0):

Most common build tools cannot handle circular dependencies, but there is no reason why  a manual incremental build cannot include circular dependencies as long as there is at least a starting binary version of one of the two jars.

Since build tools cannot handle such dependencies, in practice it is rarely encountered and is considered bad design by most java developers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stay away from it -- I appreciate the expert opinions.